# NuGet Boost include not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, boost, nuget

I have a problem with NuGet and boost. I have installed boost library and boost_thread library and used them before without any problems in my project.

After installing boost_serialization and pulling changes from my git master repo my project broke.

Here is the git diff from the packages.config file:

```
1    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
2    <packages>
    -  <package id="boost" version="1.54.0.157" targetFramework="Native" />
    -  <package id="boost_chrono-vc110" version="1.54.0.157" targetFramework="Native" />
    -  <package id="boost_date_time-vc110" version="1.54.0.157" targetFramework="Native" />
    -  <package id="boost_system-vc110" version="1.54.0.157" targetFramework="Native" />
    -  <package id="boost_thread-vc110" version="1.54.0.157" targetFramework="Native" />
3   +  <package id="boost" version="1.55.0.10" targetFramework="Native" />
4   +  <package id="boost_chrono-vc110" version="1.55.0.10" targetFramework="Native" />
5   +  <package id="boost_date_time-vc110" version="1.55.0.10" targetFramework="Native" />
6   +  <package id="boost_serialization-vc110" version="1.55.0.10" targetFramework="Native" />
7   +  <package id="boost_system-vc110" version="1.55.0.10" targetFramework="Native" />
8   +  <package id="boost_thread-vc110" version="1.55.0.10" targetFramework="Native" />
9    </packages>
```

Relevant section of git diff from the vcxproj file:

```
   <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
-    <Import Project="packages\boost.1.54.0.157\build\native\boost.targets" Condition="Exists('packages\boost.1.54.0.157\build\native\boost.targets')" />
-    <Import Project="packages\boost_thread-vc110.1.54.0.157\build\native\boost_thread-vc110.targets" Condition="Exists('packages\boost_thread-vc110.1.54.0.157\build\native\boost_thread-vc110.targets')" />
-    <Import Project="packages\boost_system-vc110.1.54.0.157\build\native\boost_system-vc110.targets" Condition="Exists('packages\boost_system-vc110.1.54.0.157\build\native\boost_system-vc110.targets')" />
-    <Import Project="packages\boost_date_time-vc110.1.54.0.157\build\native\boost_date_time-vc110.targets" Condition="Exists('packages\boost_date_time-vc110.1.54.0.157\build\native\boost_date_time-vc110.targets')" />
-    <Import Project="packages\boost_chrono-vc110.1.54.0.157\build\native\boost_chrono-vc110.targets" Condition="Exists('packages\boost_chrono-vc110.1.54.0.157\build\native\boost_chrono-vc110.targets')" />
+    <Import Project="packages\boost_chrono-vc110.1.55.0.10\build\native\boost_chrono-vc110.targets" Condition="Exists('packages\boost_chrono-vc110.1.55.0.10\build\native\boost_chrono-vc110.targets')" />
+    <Import Project="packages\boost_date_time-vc110.1.55.0.10\build\native\boost_date_time-vc110.targets" Condition="Exists('packages\boost_date_time-vc110.1.55.0.10\build\native\boost_date_time-vc110.targets')" />
+    <Import Project="packages\boost_system-vc110.1.55.0.10\build\native\boost_system-vc110.targets" Condition="Exists('packages\boost_system-vc110.1.55.0.10\build\native\boost_system-vc110.targets')" />
+    <Import Project="packages\boost_thread-vc110.1.55.0.10\build\native\boost_thread-vc110.targets" Condition="Exists('packages\boost_thread-vc110.1.55.0.10\build\native\boost_thread-vc110.targets')" />
+    <Import Project="packages\boost_serialization-vc110.1.55.0.10\build\native\boost_serialization-vc110.targets" Condition="Exists('packages\boost_serialization-vc110.1.55.0.10\build\native\boost_serialization-vc110.targets')" />
+    <Import Project="packages\boost.1.55.0.10\build\native\boost.targets" Condition="Exists('packages\boost.1.55.0.10\build\native\boost.targets')" />
   </ImportGroup>
```

It seems like the version of the dependency was updated too. I tried to change it back to 1.54 but it didn't solve the problem either. I get errors like:

IntelliSense: cannot open source file "boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp"

I tried including it with both

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
```

and

```
#include "boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp"
```

How do I solve this?

EDIT1: Additional info is, that I have started using GitHub instead of TortoiseGit. Don't know if this matters.

Comment: Something to do with [this](http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/11/boost-migrating) maybe?

Comment: No, Boost 1.55 Nuget package have nothing to do with Boost migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem got solved by reinstalling the NuGet extension.

Comment: Which version of Boost are you using now, 1.55 or 1.54?

Comment: 1.55 the latest version.